# I can't open jnlp file in UBUNTU 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: java, proxy

```
*****************:~/Downloads$ javaws jaligner.jnlp
Unable to use Firefox's proxy settings. Using "DIRECT" as proxy type.
Unable to use Firefox's proxy settings. Using "DIRECT" as proxy type.
netx: Initialization Error: Could not initialize application. (Fatal: Application Error: Cannot grant permissions to unsigned jars. Application requested security permissions, but jars are not signed.)
net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Initialization Error: Could not initialize application. The application has not been initialized, for more information execute javaws from the command line.
    at java.desktop/net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplication(Launcher.java:822)
    at java.desktop/net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.launchApplication(Launcher.java:531)
    at java.desktop/net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher$TgThread.run(Launcher.java:945)
Caused by: net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Application Error: Cannot grant permissions to unsigned jars. Application requested security permissions, but jars are not signed.
    at java.desktop/net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader$SecurityDelegateImpl.getClassLoaderSecurity(JNLPClassLoader.java:2485)
    at java.desktop/net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.setSecurity(JNLPClassLoader.java:385)
    at java.desktop/net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.initializeResources(JNLPClassLoader.java:806)
    at java.desktop/net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.<init>(JNLPClassLoader.java:338)
    at java.desktop/net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.createInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:421)
    at java.desktop/net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.getInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:495)
    at java.desktop/net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.getInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.desktop/net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplication(Launcher.java:814)
    ... 2 more
```

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/143805/524752